# POSTGRES - Query has no destination for result data with trimmed mean

Tags: postgresql

I'm new at postgresql and i'm trying to make a function that will return the trimmed mean about all table data. When i try to run this query i get the error message:

`ERROR:  query has no destination for result data`

This is the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION media_truncada(
    coluna TEXT,
    percentualTruncado NUMERIC) 
RETURNS REAL AS $$
    BEGIN
    IF coluna = 'tempo_ciclo' THEN
        WITH limites AS
            (SELECT
                (AVG(evento_tempo_ciclo.tempo_ciclo) - STDDEV_SAMP(evento_tempo_ciclo.tempo_ciclo) * percentualTruncado) as limite_inferior,
                (AVG(evento_tempo_ciclo.tempo_ciclo) + STDDEV_SAMP(evento_tempo_ciclo.tempo_ciclo) * percentualTruncado) as limite_superior
                FROM evento_tempo_ciclo)
            SELECT 
                AVG(evento_tempo_ciclo.tempo_ciclo) as media
                FROM evento_tempo_ciclo
                WHERE tempo_ciclo BETWEEN (SELECT limite_inferior FROM limites) AND (SELECT limite_superior FROM limites);
    ELSE
        WITH limites AS
                (SELECT
                    (AVG(evento_tempo_ciclo.tempo_ciclo_liquido) - STDDEV_SAMP(evento_tempo_ciclo.tempo_ciclo_liquido) * percentualTruncado) as limite_inferior,
                    (AVG(evento_tempo_ciclo.tempo_ciclo_liquido) + STDDEV_SAMP(evento_tempo_ciclo.tempo_ciclo_liquido) * percentualTruncado) as limite_superior
                    FROM evento_tempo_ciclo)
                SELECT 
                    AVG(evento_tempo_ciclo.tempo_ciclo_liquido) as media
                    FROM evento_tempo_ciclo
                    WHERE tempo_ciclo BETWEEN (SELECT limite_inferior FROM limites) AND (SELECT limite_superior FROM limites);
    END IF;
    RETURN media;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+%22query+has+no+destination+for+result+data%22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error message because you execute a query in your function, but nothing happens with the output.  `RETURN media` doesn't actually return anything because media isn't defined, it's only the alias of the column in your query, which is unknown after the query ends.

You will either need to:

Assign the result to a variable:

```
DECLARE media REAL;
BEGIN
  WITH (...) SELECT AVG(evento_tempo_ciclo.tempo_ciclo_liquido) INTO media ...
  RETURN media;
END ...
```

Or return the query as the result:

```
RETURN QUERY AS WITH (...) SELECT ...
```

Or just use an SQL function rather than plpgsql:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION media_truncada(
    coluna TEXT,
    percentualTruncado NUMERIC) 
  RETURNS REAL AS $$
    ...
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

If you aren't 100% certain that your query will never return more than 1 result, you will need to add a `LIMIT 1` to your query.